# Refresh values with speed

Tags: android, refresh

I'd like to monitor the value which is readvalue in this code in real time.
i tried to use while roof, for roof, do while roof but they all didn't work!

please give me some suggestion.tuu

```
 package remote.bluetooth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class KbdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView Read;
    //    TypeView KbdView = new TypeView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.typeview); // KbdActivity에 TypeView를 입히기.
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {   
       Read = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read);
       Read.setText(String.valueOf(Main.readvalue));
       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally wrong.
You are writing code in the UI thread and blocking it with your cycle. While your code is executing, system can't redraw your UI and handle events from UI. You must write your cycle in separate thread and in the UI thread only update UI. You must use non blocking operation to delay your task:

```
 package remote.bluetooth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class KbdActivity extends Activity {

    TextView Read;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //    TypeView KbdView = new TypeView(this);
       setContentView(R.layout.typeview); // KbdActivity에 TypeView를 입히기.
       Read = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read);
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {   
             Read.setText(String.valueOf(Main.readvalue));
             handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
          }
       }
       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
     }
}
```

And remember, don't do long tasks in main thread. Your UI will became laggy or even freeze like in your code.

Please read some books about java.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But your code shows the error "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement"

Comment: @user3769541 I wrote this code on site and don't check spell. I'm trying to show solution, and I think that you know java syntax rules. I updated question.

Comment: @user3769541 remove braces before final Hadler handler = new ... These code must be placed in your onCreate method of activity

Comment: There is no braces before final handler. It shows error that [The type new Runnable(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Runnable.run()], and Return type for the method is missing(findViewById)

Comment: @user3769541 I updated my answer. Please read some books about Java. You don't understand syntax of it. I can't spend a time to explain what is java, what is class and so on. I've tried to help with your problem, but your problem in your knowledge, in your empty knoweledge

Comment: whatever, your answer doesn't work anyway., I solved problem byebye

Comment: @user3769541 I'm glad that you solved your problem. For other people who will facing problem like you, please post your solution and accept it. It's important for stackoverflow to have solution for all questions.